# Django: Hidden form FIELD (not widget) with `form.as_table`

Tags: django, django-forms

One can add a `disabled` attribute to a widget by passing in `attrs={'disabled':True}`. However there also exists a [disabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) form field (not widget) argument, which tells Django this field is disabled, and then Django handles it accordingly in the validation logic and also setting the HTML disabled attribute.

Now similarly with regards to hidden, one can set a widget to be hidden passing in `attrs={'hidden':True}`, but the problem with this is that it only hides the HTML input widget, the label associated with it still shown. How does one get around this problem (when using `form.as_table`, I understand one can loop through the visible and hidden fields and manually build up a form, but thats not what I am looking for.

Under [Core field arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#core-field-arguments) I would expect to see a hidden attribute.

Comment: I belive the template should be overridden since you need to edit the default rendering of the form... This is a nice way to customize templates for forms in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Comment: The easiest option would be to set an empty label for any field you're hiding.